# R new column with raising value based on condition in other column

Tags: r, for-loop, counting

I would like to have a new column where after 7 values of 1 a new raising number appears:

`data <- data.frame(changes = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 ,0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))`

new column should look like this:
 `data <- data.frame(new_column = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)`

I used the following code but the numbers aren´t changing.

```
  group_counter <- 1
  new_value_counter <- 1
  new_column <- integer(length(data$values))  
  for (i in seq_along(data$values)) {
    if (data$values[i] == 1) {
      group_counter <- group_counter + 1
      if (group_counter == 7) {
        new_value_counter <- new_value_counter + 1
        group_counter <- 0
      }
      new_column[i] <- new_value_counter
    } else {
      group_counter <- 0
    }
  }
  
  return(new_column)
}


data$new_column <- generate_new_column(data)
```

Comment: `ceiling` and `cumsum` will do: `data$new_colum <- ceiling(cumsum(data$changes)/7)`